# Migrate artifacts from custom Sonatype Nexus installation to Maven Central

Tags: maven, nexus, sonatype, maven-central

Use case is: Migrate artifacts (jar, sources, javadoc, pom) from custom Sonatype Nexus installation to Maven Central

I am able to do it manually (and therefore it can be automated) but I am wondering whether there is already a plugin / tool that achieves this goal?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Are you trying to publish artifacts on maven central, or migrate artifacts from your Nexus install from a repo to another one?

Comment: I have my artifacts already published in my Nexus (the project is released) and I would like to upload those artifacts also to Maven Central. Right now the process is: download all the necessary artifacts from my Nexus, sign them, bundle them and upload the bundles manually in Maven Central UI